# How to convert hours to minutes?

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

When I use decimals in the formula it works like how it should work. It shows perfectly the hours and minutes (hh:mm). The problem starts when I use integers like 45 in the example below. The result is 0 which is pretty logical. Actually what I want is the outcome "45:0". What do I need to do to the following code:

```
WHEN MOD(ROUND((45) * 60), 60) > 9 THEN
  to_char(FLOOR((45))) || ':' || MOD(ROUND(ABS((45)) * 60), 60)
ELSE
  "0:00"
```

Hope someone else could help me out with this.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Add a condition like `when round(number) = number then do something`,

Comment: Yes, you are correct! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is good, you just need to remove the `WHEN` condition along with `ELSE` part.

Or let us know its purpose ! why you want to use `0:00` when minute part is `9` or less then 9 (i.e after point / fraction part is lower then .15 or no fraction at all)